# Create vector by groups, rows in r

Tags: r, vector

After very long research I couldn't find a way to create the vector based on the row value. I want to group some data by gender:

```
gender   height
woman     123
man       124
man       125
other     234
woman     127
```

In this dataframe I want to create vectors which contain women's and men's heights, for example:

```
woman <- c(123, 127)
man <- c(124, 125)
```

I have tried

asv<- as.vector(data$gender[gender=="woman"])

but it completely didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `height` values after subsetting for `gender`.

```
man <- df$height[df$gender == 'man']
woman <- df$height[df$gender == 'woman']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a moment ago I have tried:

```
dfc <- c(data$height)[data$gender=="woman"]
```

and it seems to work too

Comment: you don't need `c` there.